# What other events besides Winter Bash are held by Stack Overflow, and how often?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

How often does Stack Overflow hold events like Winter Bash or others?

Is Winter Bash the only event they host?

Comment: This depends on your definition of event. They usually have a thing around the 1st of april, and you could count the welcoming/summer of love thingy every six years as an event as well.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think the question is only about regular events. We could also include Joel's occasional actions (e.g. the Steve Jobs banner), but those aren't on a regular schedule - they are usually in response to something in the outside world.

Comment: @S.L.Barth My point is that the question is pretty unclear. SE hosts many things that could be considered events. Some of them are only online, some in the real world, some on regular schedules. If we're talking about online events that occur yearly, we could also include elections, open-source advertising, the survey, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have Winter Bash once a year, in December/January.

Stack Overflow also has a yearly April Fool's joke, but it is something different every year.
The most important difference is that Winter Bash is for (usually) constructive interaction with the site. The April Fool's joke is always something silly, and does not interact with the core activities of the site.

We also have a yearly Developer Survey, as [Erik von Asmuth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379679/winter-bash-and-other-events/379680?noredirect=1#comment666839_379679) and [Gimby](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379679/winter-bash-and-other-events/379680?noredirect=1#comment666851_379680) point out in comments.

We also have moderator elections, which are in general once a year. However, moderator elections aren't regular events - they are held when the moderator team believes that more moderators are needed.

Comment: @Gimby Annual survey I'm going to include. Moderator elections aren't yearly... might add them for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Also - company doesn't decide when moderator elections happen.  The moderator team decides that.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks, updated the answer.

Comment: Winter for the ***Northern*** Hemisphere (of the Earth), that is. The Australians, among others, may not be amused.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Changed it to a hopefully more hemisphere-neutral wording :-)

Comment: @Makoto While we're involved in the discussion and can request new moderators, when/if the elections are held is ultimately decided by the company

Comment: @Rob:  That's news to me.  Could've sworn it was largely at the behest of moderators when there were more flags than could go around.  I'm a bit surprised by that?  Didn't realize they had to get involved.

Comment: @Makoto largely, yes. But we don't have a button to start an election :)

Comment: So they're...a rubber stamp in effect?  Nothing can happen without them pressing The Button™, or are they doing other things?  Do enlighten me, I genuinely had no idea.

Comment: @Makoto generally, if mods ask for an election, they'll get one. Sometimes due to the workload of CMs, elections may be delayed quite a bit longer than the mods may have liked... But so far as I've seen, they always get to it. CMs also approach the mod teams to suggest elections if they feel the need. So, yes, it's mostly rubber stamping, but there still is some input/oversight from the company

Answer (score 4):

To add to S. L. Barth's answer, from time to time Stack Overflow runs contests and promotional events. There isn't anything running right now, but you can check out https://contests.stackoverflow.com/ for past events.